# Как задавать условия (см. описание)?

Tags: javascript

Как кодом задать условие: если моя строка содержит буквы и #, а также условие: если моя строка содержит ТОЛЬКО #, а также условие: если моя строка содержит ТОЛЬКО буквы?

Answer (score 1):

Не содержит ничего кроме букв a-z (без учета регистра) и #:

```
!str0.match(/[^a-z#]/i)
```

или

```
!/[^a-z#]/i.test(str0)
```

На пустой строке выражение тоже вернет `true`.

В случае `match` можно также посмотреть, что найдено.

В квадратных скобках можно перечислять любые символы. Есть и сокращения.

`[^0-9]` или `[^\d]` или `\D` -- не цифра.

`[^0-9a-z]` -- не буква и не цифра.

Comment: А если только текст или только цифры?

Comment: Или `.test()` если нужна только проверка.